# Unity Debug without the linenumber

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine

I am developing an application for the Hololens using unity,. And sometimes (since still in Debug not Release stage) I print debug statements using `Debug.Log`.

However, everytime I use that, I got my custom message *and* the following:

```
(Filename: C:/buildslave/unity/build/artifacts/generated/Metro/runtime/DebugBindings.gen.cpp Line: xx)
```

I don't know what this means, but it clutters the debug output. Is there any way to use the debug messages of the UnityEngine without these?

Comment: What are you exactly placing in the `Debug.Log()`?

Comment: Just normal stuff, like strings ("operation completed") or values ("Required time:"+reqtime). The thing is every time I call it, it prints the info and then that line above.